# Timetable of Custom Meta Data using Custom Post Type and Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, post-meta

Scenario:

I have a custom post type with custom meta boxes. Each post should represent a row in my table i.e

```
Activity 1 Jan, Activity 1 Feb and Activity 1 Mar
```

I have a custom taxonomy of terms for my Activity types:

```
Activity 1,  Activity 2 and Activity 3.
```

I am using

```
archive-custom-post.php
```

to list my custom taxonomy term links, and

```
taxonomy-custom.php
```

to show each Activity time table.

Edit: Further clarity.

My question is - how do I query the meta data of all posts associated with Activity 1 term type? I am able to query the current post with get_post_custom but that is not enough. Should I be looking at WP_Query?

Edit: Activity data example.

- Start and end date.
- Duration
- Cost
- Paypal button

Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe provide an simple example of actual data? I have trouble following the part about "associated" meta data.

Comment: Yes, I have made two edits which I hope helps to clarify what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is my own solution, improvements welcome :)

Check for term ID and assign to variable.

```
$term_id = (has_term('activity_1','activity-tax') ? 1 : (has_term('activity_2','activity-tax') ? 2 : (has_term('activity_3','activity-tax') ? 3 : '')));
```

Use term ID variable in my get_posts parameters.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'activity-post',
'order' => 'ASC',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'activity-tax', 
    'field' => 'term_id', 
    'terms' => $term_id) // Only the ID I want
)
); 
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Run over each post and create a Multiple Array of Meta Data.

```
$custom_post = array();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $custom_post[] = get_post_custom($post->ID);
}
```

Finally get the array's meta data I want.

```
foreach ( $custom_post as $key => $value ) {
    echo $value['date'][0].'<br />';
    echo $value['duration'][0].'<br />';
    echo $value['paypal'][0];
}
```